# inline editing with ajax (insert value to database)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

This can be a UX question but it can also be technical. I'm building a list with ajax and PHP. I doubt I should manipulate the DOM before the backend is finish. What will be the problem if I don't use a loader to indicate the backend activities?

Comment: Have you heard of DataTables library? Check this out: http://datatables.net/blog/Inline_editing

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? If yes please check it, if not, please provide an answer of your own and check that one, so this thread can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Well in general, as a concept of usability, you have to inform your user about the status of his/her requests. If an action takes too long and no indication exists that the request is being processed then the user might think that something doesn't work or got stuck. As a result the user will repeat the request a number of times. This won't give a chance to your site/app/program to complete its task resulting to frustration and even a belief that your product does not work.